# Typescript interface for array of anything but other arrays

Tags: typescript, tuples, variadic-tuple-types

`flatten` takes an array of any data type and produces an array with every nested array flatten.

For example, `[{}, 'hello', 2, [3, ['ay'], 'oi oi']` becomes `[{}, 'hello', 2, 3, 'ay', 'oi oi']`, and `[[[[5]]]]` becomes `[5]`.

I need an interface that would describe such a function. I started writing it thinking it would be simple, but then I stuck with describing an array of anything but other arrays.

```js
interface Flatten {
  (any[]): ...?
}
```

Any ideas are welcome, thank you :))

Answer (score 2):

It is doable in TS 4.5 (nightly version) but not in a way you expect.

Thanks to [variadic-tuple-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) you can do this:

```js
type Reducer<
  Arr extends Array<unknown>,
  Result extends Array<unknown> = []
  > =
  (Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : (Arr extends [infer H, ...infer Tail]
      ? (H extends Array<any>
        ? Reducer<[...H, ...Tail], Result> : Reducer<Tail, [...Result, H]>) : never
    )
  )

// [1,2,3]
type Result = Reducer<[[[1], [[[[[[[2]]]]]]]], 3]> 

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
type Result2 = Reducer<[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]],[[[[[[2,3,4]]]],[[[[5,6]]]]]]]>
```

> How do I use that as a function return value type?

In order to use it with function, you need to convert argument to immutable array:

```js
type Reducer<
  Arr,
  Result extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = []
  > = Arr extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> ?
  (Arr extends readonly []
    ? Result
    : (Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
      ? (H extends ReadonlyArray<any>
        ? Reducer<readonly [...H, ...Tail], Result> : Reducer<Tail, readonly [...Result, H]>) : never
    )
  ) : never


const flatten = <
  Elem,
  T extends ReadonlyArray<T | Elem>
>(arr: readonly [...T]): Reducer<T> =>
  arr.reduce((acc, elem) =>
    Array.isArray(elem)
      ? flatten(elem) as Reducer<T>
      : [...acc, elem] as Reducer<T>,
    [] as Reducer<T>
  )


const result = flatten([[[[[[1]]], 2], 3]] as const)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210910#code/C4TwDgpgBAShAmBXAxhATgHgFBSgQTTQBodYIBnRAG2CggA9gIA7ecsgQ3gHtmqQCaDiAyJmAa2bcA7swB8UALxQA2gF1SC5YLqMWbTjz4DCw0RKmyFAflIAKHQyat2aCF179VG3LmtlKGlJcAC4oB0JdZwM3D2NVAEtmADN0KAAJIigAOlyk1LQoABUOBKofXz9w9Kj9djg4-kEzDmYQOWDKqH84JFRMWKMvFVzszJzckrK1LLhA4AUw3pR0DCmqLMHPEFVRuepgLPS1OQBKKDDmCAA3dE7T0nPLm7usLGReclpkqg5gZyUUGwuAAolQIABbEi4Iq1FyGbbNESwgA+UDBkI6cjsHEIYS28RGkzUpyWCBWmCKWg6uFxaGybj6EDsOOQyCyEHBEPOihpviR2QS5CRdk5kIeXW6UB+f2coq55w49XJ-TWfMqYSJ2Q4bI5XLUUCVZCZlLk0N86kNypNaseb3en1obnmgJl-xYdhUXu9AEY1P6sgAmGZQADM-qtUA+zC+pyAA)

You should have also add second argument to `reduce` method.

More explanation you can find in my [article](https://catchts.com/flatten).

If you want to better understand how `Reducer` utility type work, see this exmaple:

```js
const Reducer = <T,>(Arr: ReadonlyArray<T>, Result: ReadonlyArray<T> = [])
  : ReadonlyArray<T> => {

  if (Arr.length === 0) {
    return Result
  }
  const [Head, ...Tail] = Arr;

  if (Array.isArray(Head)) {
    return Reducer([...Head, ...Tail], Result)
  }

  return Reducer(Tail, [...Result, Head])
}
```

Comment: That looks really complicated to me.
How do I use that as a function return value type?

Comment: I will ad more explanation later

Comment: [Result](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210910#code/C4TwDgpgBAShAmBXAxhATgHgFBSgQTTSggA9gIA7eAZ1ggEN4B7CgGxALXpA0QoGsKTAO4UAfABocdaolbBiZSjTqMW7Tt14ChosVAC8UANoBdafoPSAFJ0XkqtNA2ZsQJ87lwB+GXODSuABcULaE9spOLuruxgCWFABm6FAAEhJQAHTZCclEACr0cayeXj6hqRGOqq4ahFr0FCBigWVQvnBIqJjOam4m2ZnpWdmFxaYZcLLy+iGdKOgYY6wZvbWxg1P+GammYgCUUCEUEABu6K370ldYyCzUComs9MAOhlBLVSpwfXVcPHxBCJxBIxNZ6IQQvl9nMEAtMPlLPoAN7SZzARBoChQCFoTLOLoQazg5DIDLITFoQ4GMSospxRKhTQgTJxajM6wUwj7Q50trozHYp4vBycyn7ADcrQAvlhWgKsQNsvRSeTKaVpVdZVggA) is not working

Comment: @PYTHONDEVELOPER999 please see updated code

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the data types flat array should return, you may define it like below:

```
type Flat = string|number|FlatObj;
type FlatArr = Array<Flat>;
type FlatObj = {[key: string]: Flat|FlatArr};
```

In your example you had nested empty object, so I assume you want it to contain only flat arrays too, `FlatObj` is definition of it.

Now if you try to assign nested arrays in any `FlatArr` variable, it should complain about it.

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=30&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiA8gIwFZQLxQN4G0DWEIAXFAM7ABOAlnAOYC6pAhggL4DcAUKJFAGIAbZsEzkqtOgB84AVwC2yCJSlCRKVN17Q1wGJUpj9lZiAA8ugHxbwO4cA1i8hEuJr0mA+6vvHOXLgAzWTgAY2BqAHs4KGoyXQ0ACki0UngkNABKUhT0OK91NBwuKChBCFFA+zEqWQhuUsDIw0TQ6IooF1iY3Mzi0tLqQKhE41MAOjixkGS0AiIGPoAyJagAQjjdY1nUeZBFvqqRMUDmQTJ6koGIc+ghke1I4dy9hkwMLAByXIhwz6gVutNvYki8XAcoEdRFhTrcGlA2FdKBVZJQYlDuIigiFwlEYsCRNtmAYWAhcIsWAZYmQCnoqdgruVKtUsLVLqViZRxvJmGBEolqMAIPI+hhLP0BvdRgYJlMZTNBcLMocWZCzhd4aUbhdYsNEo9hor5O8vj8-gDVht4iC0AKhSKVccYer2QjMvDkcBUej7JiAm04B0oUK4MYxIlOaSQOTsrSw2KJQGg74SXGqVhyfCmi0k6IjVAnlBOX0GQNdSNppMyNM7UrHXSuWBZGQABaJcYd4MQUMGWsOzVQbV3PUG2L2k1QT4Udx0T714zjJutvvuq5a27l-W2Qv5j5fOSKZRzyEpxvNttG1dloeb0e7j6Ts3AY9QhdLttduBJS9XhFIlFoiehIGH6XC5kBwAho4WA7GkCAaLGCRFAmpZlBUEEaKQSHoFg2D+I0zQjOBXS0AWWQSoMeqVnKJgzGCCzKhhczgic9ghts9H7L+646lKo6cW8e6TtOkgvjauwsVgAkDjefHbs8zELBOnwHkolBiYUElKVJin7DJG5yZAhYCcpT4aQ4umCRBUG2gJv6IqUnrekxmhcFi4EAPqcqxIjsb2uB4QANFAACMwW4BFADMDAxcF2AAB6kBFAAsMVsIs3BJpE5TjIIkR0IkXkGJkYHtNlEC5flArWsBlCFcW7pAA)

If you are looking for a Type Guard, here one example for `FlatArr` and `FlatObj`:

```
type AnyObj = {[key: string]: any};

function isFlatObj(obj: AnyObj): obj is FlatObj {
  let flat = true;
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && !isFlatArr(obj[key])) flat = false;
    else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !isFlatObj(obj[key])) flat = false;
  }
  return flat;
}

function isFlatArr(arr: any[]): arr is FlatArr {
  let flat = true;
  arr.map((item) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) flat = false;
    else if (typeof item === 'object' && !isFlatObj(item)) flat = false;
  });
  return flat;
}
```

To make FlatArr, you can define a function for it. I made two functions below. One makes Arrays flat, the other makes sure object arrays are flat too:

```
const flattenArr = (arr: any[]): FlatArr => {
  const flatArr: FlatArr = [];
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) flatArr.push(...flattenArr(item));
    else if (typeof item === 'string') flatArr.push(item);
    else if (typeof item === 'number') flatArr.push(item);
    else if (typeof item === 'object') flatArr.push(flattenObj(item));
  }
  return flatArr;
}

const flattenObj = (obj: AnyObj): FlatObj => {
  let flatObj: FlatObj = {};
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) flatObj[key] = flattenArr(obj[key]);
    else if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') flatObj[key] = obj[key];
    else if (typeof obj[key] === 'number') flatObj[key] = obj[key];
    else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') flatObj[key] = flattenObj(obj[key]);
  }
  return flatObj;
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Typescript doesn't warn me when I simply return the same array

Comment: Maybe rename `FlatArray` to `FlatArr`, since the `FlatArray` might be defined somewhere. I tested the code with this change and TypeScript (4.4.2) does warn me about any nested arrays when variable type is `FlatArr` which is the return type of the flatten function in the above example.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210910#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiAbAhjAglKOAXjnyi0QB4BnGKASwDsBzAH0YFcBbAI2ClYBvOAG0A1sEQAuOLQYtW1RLwgZ23PlAC6MuUzade-OAF8AfAG4AUFaQp02GDGCNicABRYCMrI0QitAEpiMwccMmsrAGMIRlo4ADNHZ0YZTBwUt08CYKJQwSs4IrgYuPgk8IIKNMcyNwDrYrgAembE6A9S+PpnLjgIBLgvKGCCptamuHpB9zIKADp6ajnEdx7gLkDgirwqxHmwDmoAC3d5852Utd6txuKJpuAMalRpjztgAane4iISAHI9Cx-ttansDkdTutNncig9ik8XlMZh8vtDfgDDJoQYkweR9ocTtcNoFYS02uM2lwKHAAO6+eAwCAlY7AKJiOCMYC0YAAE36PAAVmz4MMKNQEBBmayoMB5oV7m0TAqirKYBwoK4ROd5jsVlprMqgA). TS doesn't require type guarding.